# How to scroll to position on ScrollView using databinding?

Tags: android, data-binding, scrollview

I use databinding in my android apps but there's one question no one could answer me...

If my ScrollView contains some **TextInputLayout** containing **InputditText** elements how could i scroll to a specific textinputlayout by using databinding?
Nowadays I use Butterknife, binding the scrollview, and have to scroll to this position of that view via that manually but I'm wondering if there's no other way to do that.

Anybody an idea?

Comment: Probably not the entirely different approach you're looking for. But I think you can get rid of butterknife at least by using the binder's fields:
binding.myscroller.scrollTo
(If you set the view's id to R.id.myscroller here)

Comment: Yeah @Till, you're absolutly right. After some more research I got the fact, that I can get a binded View like that! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a little custom BindingAdapter that scrolls to the position defined by a variable containing a view id.
I know it contains a *findViewById* but for me that's ok.

```
@BindingAdapter("scrollTo")
public static void scrollTo(ScrollView view, int viewId) {

    if (viewId == 0) {
        view.scrollTo(0, 0);
        return;
    }

    View v = view.findViewById(viewId);
    view.scrollTo(0, v.getTop());
    v.requestFocus();
}
```

Because of using databinding, I can easily add this adapter in my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>
    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.grumpyshoe.myapp.features.dashboard.viewmodel.DashboardViewmodel"/>
    </data>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:id="@+id/root_dashboard"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="@android:color/transparent"
              android:focusable="true"
              android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
              android:orientation="vertical">

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/bank_account_scroll_wrapper"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            app:scrollTo="@{viewModel.focusedViewId}"> 

        [...]
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: Don't overlook the `static` in the method declaration. I glossed right over it in @grumpyshoe 's answer.

Comment: How do you call the`scrollTo` function if i can't pass the ScrollView as a parameter?

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos I don't understand why you can't pass the ScrollView as a parameter!?
Any BindingAdapter that you write will have it's own view as first parameter and the second one is the one you passed in.
Can you explain more or give al small example of what or where you wanna use this?

Comment: My fault sorry, i had to clean build the project because it couldn't find the ScrollView through findViewBy